# On Android how do I wrapping text inside in a bezier path

Tags: android, text, word-wrap

I have some text i need to wrap inside of a bezier path. On iOS its pretty simple to use Core Text to set the path of the text container and draw. Is there an easy way to do this without using a web view? I need the background of text to be transparent and the rendering to be fast.

APIs appear to be on. Looking for an example of in.. Path is coming from an in-house tool that exports photoshop shapes. It could be:

1/2 circle is just an example. We can have any shape that we want and its not outside. But inside. The path needs to be free form its coming from an in house design tool. Again inside not outside..

[image]

Comment: Hi Scott did you find out how to draw text inside of a path? If yes, it would be nice if you could share your code. Thanks!

Comment: No. We ended up going another way with the text.

Comment: To achieve the same goal (have text in a free formed shape)? If so, please let us know! :o)

Comment: hey what alternative did u used there ??

Answer (score -1):

I would try this:

1. Create a [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html)

   `Path path = new Path();`
2. Use `Path.quadTo()` or `Path.cubicTo()` methods to draw your curve

and then:

```
myCanvas.drawTextOnPath(myText, path, offset, 0, myPaint);
```

Comment: If I'm reading this api right draws text to the outside. Not inside of the shape. I need to wrap the text block to the inside of the path. Like wrap the text inside a 1/2 moon shape. (just an example).

Comment: I see, but if you choose the right radius you can achieve the same effect adding an half circle on the Path like this path.addCircle(x, y, radius, Path.Direction.CW); and then drawTextOnPath

Comment: 1/2 circle is just an example. We can have any shape that we want and its not outside. But inside. The path could be:

*************************
°
°
°
°

Comment: Ok, understood, for what I know, the only way to draw text _on_ any path using the standard API is this. I wish you good work. Have a great day.